# cannot convert 'double' to 'double (*)[5]' for argument '1' to 'void one_set_avrg(double (*)[5])'

Tags: c++

The question wants me to create a two-dimensional array and there will be several tasks which required me to do it in different function. Like count the average for each row, calculate the average for whole array, sort the array in ascending order, and output the largest value that I have keyed in.

The code works if I don't separate it into different functions, but the questions asked me to separate it into different function and I ended up with these errors:

1. cannot convert 'double' to 'double (*)[5]' for argument '1' to 'void
   one_set_avrg(double (*)[5])'
2. cannot convert 'double' to 'double (*)[5]' for argument '1' to 'void 
   avrg_allset(double (*)[5])'
3. cannot convert 'double' to 'double (*)[5]' for argument '1' to 'double
   largest_value(double (*)[5])'

I would appreciate it very much if you could tell me what's wrong with my code and how could I solve it.

Here is the error part:

```
    one_set_avrg(A[3][5]);
    avrg_allset(A[3][5]);
    cout <<endl;

    cout <<"Largest number is: \n"<<largest_value(A[3][5])<<endl;


    return 0;

}
```

Comment: Your question fails to meet the "minimal" requirement for a [mcve]. Although the compilation error is obvious, stackoverflow.com is not someplace you can simply dump a massive pile of code, with a compilation error somewhere, and have someone fix your code for you. You need to show at least the minimal amount of effort of putting together a reasonable question, with all irrelevant filler removed. Bad questions should not be rewarded with an answer. You need to edit your question, and remove all code that's not relevant to the compilation error. See [mcve] in the Help Center for more info.

Comment: Sorry for that.. Doesn't really know how do this works

Comment: That's what the Help Center is for: to help you learn how to ask questions.

Comment: Your functions expect an array. And you are passing just a single element. Hence the error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't have to mention the dimensions of the array while calling a function.

So, your code would be:

```
one_set_avrg( A );
avrg_allset( A );


cout <<"Largest number is: \n"<< largest_value( A ) <<endl;
```

Here's your live code: http://ideone.com/tGdhDa

Comment: Thank you so much mate! And I have to apologize that consumed you so much time to read through my codes.

Comment: @SengKai: You are welcome! :) Kindly mark my answer as accepted and follow the rules for asking the question.